# Podcasting: Pipe internet audio to conference calls

Tags: audio, skype, recording, podcasts

I have a podcast and we use Skype and Audio Hijack to record all of us.

How would I go about piping audio so the other people on the Skype conference call can hear it real time? I would like a software solution if possible. I realize they are several hardware solutions available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Soundflower to create a virtual input device, and use that as your input device for Skype.  Soundflower is free and is available at http://www.cycling74.com/products/soundflower

Comment: looks like it's for OS X only. Anything similar for Windows?